# Upload images from Flutter

Tags: python, flask

I want to upload images from the mobile application to my Firestore using a Flask API.
The app is uploading a list of int that represents the image.  The length of the list is really long, over a thousand I believe.
I'm sending this list of ints in the request json.

1. How can I upload this list of ints to Firebase storage using the Firebase module for Flask.
2. Is using a list of ints to upload the image even the correct way?
3. If not, how can I upload the image using the Flask API?

This the code I have so far, and it's a mess :) :

```
def post(self):
    request_data = request.get_json()
    baqala_id = request_data["userID"]
    imageBytes = request_data["imageBytes"]
    # imageFile = request_data["imageFile"]

    bucket = storage.bucket("bucket_name.appspot.com")

    blob = bucket.blob(f"{baqala_id}/{imageBytes}")
    # blob = bucket.blob(f"{baqala_id}/{imageFile}")

    upload = blob.upload_from_string(imageBytes)
    # upload = blob.upload_from_file(imageFile)

    return {"message": "upload succesfull"}, 200
```

Note: I can't using the Firebase plugin for Flutter because it's too slow and cannot be used in a separate Isolate.

Comment: using list of ints seems very odd method. If you have to send it as JSON then popular method is to convert bytes from file to `base64` string and send it . Or send it as bytes in using `form`

Comment: Interesting. I did not know about base64. I have a question. [base64Decode] takes a string in dart. What should I pass to this method?  Should I read the file as string?

Comment: I think it will work like in Python and in Python `base64.b64decode` expects string already converted to `base64` - ie. `import base64` and `print( base64.b64decode(b'SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=').decode() )` gives `'Hello World'` - so it may get data received from JSON downloaded from request, or fetched from database. And if you want to convert file to `base64` then probably it has something like `base64Encode`